# SelectedItem not reachable from DataGrid in RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a `DataGrid` which holds a number of objects. Within that DataGrid, I have a `RowDetailsTemplate` to house all of the hierarchical data. I want to be able to select the object from within that DataGrid, but so far haven't had any luck with the following code

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="leagueList" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Leagues}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLeague}"
              Margin="0,0,5,0" ColumnWidth="1*"
              CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <utility:SubtractValueConverter x:Key="SubtractValueConverter"/>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Expanded="Expander_Expanded" Collapsed="Expander_Collapsed"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="League" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Initials" Binding="{Binding Initials}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:Team}">
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTeam, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" GridLinesVisibility="All"
                          Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=leagueList, Converter={StaticResource SubtractValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=50}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ColumnWidth="*" Margin="1,1,1,1" BorderThickness="2">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nickname" Binding="{Binding Nickname}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

The `SelectedTeam` Property is what I want to be called when a `Team` is selected, but it doesn't appear to be bound to that property, even though I'm specifying it as such.

```
    public Team SelectedTeam
    {
        get => _SelectedTeam;
        set
        {
            _SelectedTeam = value;
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Selected Team is: " + _SelectedTeam.Nickname);
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedTeam");
        }
    }
```

When I run my app, I don't even get the `MessageBox` popup when I select a Team, but I should.

The entire grid populates properly, I just can't get the SelectedItem from the inner DataGrid.

Comment: I guess this could be the issue: https://www.telerik.com/forums/sub-gridview-details-databinding-mvvm#I74ApHn26E-zC_yR3LJ6fA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using both Jan's comment [link](https://www.telerik.com/forums/sub-gridview-details-databinding-mvvm#I74ApHn26E-zC_yR3LJ6fA) and Satish's answers, I've found the solution.

The child `DataGrid` needs to find the DataContext of it's parent, so using `RelativeResource` to point to the `UserControl` type will work, followed by inserting `DataContext` in front of my property type. So the `SelectedItem` line of code appears as follows:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedTeam, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is inside the template, it is difficult to bind the selected item,
what you can do is use RelativeSource, below is the syntax & example.

```
SelectedItem = {Binding Path=SelectedTeam, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type typeOfAncestor}}}
```

typeOfAncestor :- Type of Ancestor is the type of class for which you have provided the namespace in the Declaration of Xaml, which the namespace of the viewmodel.

For example:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
```

which needs to be at the top of the xaml page

```
SelectedItem = {Binding Path=SelectedTeam, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ViemModelName}}}
```

Relative Source relates or points towards the property.
Now what happens is the SelectedTeam is binded from the View Model to this Selected Item Property.

Hope this helps you.
Thanks,